# Por que o Spring boot não usa EntityManager?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot

Há algum tempo estava estudando *Java EE* com apostilas. Usava *JSF* e *Hibernate*. Agora estou trabalhando com *Spring* e *Hibernate*. Mas diferente do *Java EE*, eu não crio nenhum *EntityManager*.

Ele não é obrigatório?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

O Spring Boot possui várias funcionalidades já internalizadas e prontas para uso em suas libs, facilitando a configuração ao criar tudo do zero.

Conforme descrito na documentação:

> The Spring Framework provides extensive support for working with SQL databases, from direct JDBC access using JdbcTemplate to complete “object relational mapping” technologies such as Hibernate. Spring Data provides an additional level of functionality: creating Repository implementations directly from interfaces and using conventions to generate queries from your method names.

Ou seja, com Spring Boot e Spring Data você pode utilizar várias interfaces para utilizar coisas em comum, como queries baseada nas propriedades de suas classes, entre outras coisas.

Várias coisas configuradas no `persistence.xml` podem facilmente ser implementadas no `application.properties`, conforme o exemplo de configuração abaixo:

```
app.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/test
app.datasource.username=dbuser
app.datasource.password=dbpass
app.datasource.configuration.maximum-pool-size=30
```

As configurações relacionadas à datasources podem ser conferidas através [deste link](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-sql.html)

### Como utilizar o Entity Manager com Spring Boot?

Caso sua aplicação demande de configuração do `Entity Manager` (utilizando Spring Boot com Spring Batch por exemplo), você pode facilmente expor/configurar seu `Entity Manager` conforme o seguinte exemplo:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager() {
    JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager(entityManagerFactory);
    return jpaTransactionManager;
}
```

Neste meu exemplo utilizei o `JpaTransactionManager` em minha aplicação para flexibilizar meu trabalho no batch.

Ao utilizar o `EntityManagerFactory` você terá controle total sobre o que o manager irá realizar, conforme descrito neste trecho da [documentação](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html):

> To take full control of the configuration of the EntityManagerFactory, you need to add a @Bean named ‘entityManagerFactory’. Spring Boot auto-configuration switches off its entity manager in the presence of a bean of that type.

Uma explicação adicional também pode ser encontrada [nesta thread do StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33074547/spring-boot-configure-entitymanager).

Espero ter ajudado!

Answer (score 1):

> Ele não é obrigatório?

O `EntityManager` continua sendo obrigatório e também está disponível no Spring, mas o uso **direto** dele pelo desenvolvedor vai depender de como ele precisa consultar a informação que ele deseja.

Como o Spring traz diversas facilidades para buscas de dados em bancos de dados, por meio do `CrudRepository`, `JpaRepository`, etc, o `EntityManager` ainda é usado de forma **indireta** pela aplicação, pois o seu uso fica oculto sob estas interfaces.

Se verificar, por exemplo, qual classe implementa o método `save` do `CrudRepository`, verá que é  a `SimpleJpaRepository`. Olhando o [código-fonte desta classe](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/SimpleJpaRepository.java), teremos o `EntityManager` sendo usado:

```
@Transactional
public <S extends T> S save(S entity) {
    if (this.entityInformation.isNew(entity)) {
        this.em.persist(entity); // em é o EntityManager 
        return entity;
    } else {
        return this.em.merge(entity);
    }
}
```

Nos casos que você deseja fazer uma consulta mais complexa, envolvendo Criteria ou JPQL, você precisará usar o `EntityManager` diretamente, mesmo com o Spring. Para isto, basta injetar o `EntityManager` na sua classe:

```
@Autowired
private EntityManager em;
```

E fazer a consulta que desejar:

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT pessoa FROM Pessoa pessoa");
return query.getResultList();
```

Como pode ver, o Entity Manager continua existindo, porém o Spring criou algumas classes para abstrair seu uso.